# Why training time of a neural network reduces when 1-2 additional hidden layers are added, keeping learning rate constant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I observed a reduction in training time when I added an additional hidden layer in the neural network. As the number of trainable parameters has increased, I was expecting an increase in training time to achieve some validation accuracy (say x), but it took less time to achieve the same accuracy with comparatively complex model.

Scenario:

- A simple separable dataset
- Multi-class classification problem
- No. of hidden layers: Before = 1 , After = 2

[Model-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Az5.png)

[Model-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnkPz.png)

Can somebody please explain this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code ? You could print the model.summary() for both models.

Comment: Maybe you need less epochs to reach that accuracy with the second model. check the number of epochs in both trainings.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco yes! Second model takes less epochs and this is my question actually that why it takes less epochs with more hidden layers/trainable parameters. Shouldn't it take more time/epochs as it has to train more parameters.

Comment: @LarebZarKhan The second model is requiring less epochs because its complexity makes it more adaptable to your data. In general a model with more parameter is more adaptable to the dataset, but it may leads to over-fit. Try to increase the training time and choose the model that, at the very end, has the highest val-acc. You can also use the early stopping, so that, once the time is up, you can select the best weights rather then the last epoch weights.

Comment: @LarebZarKhan For the summary, it is better if you add the information directly to the question, rather than adding a link to a screenshot

Comment: I believe, I found my answer here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383489/is-there-any-relation-between-the-number-of-hidden-layers-in-a-neural-network-an

Comment: That is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, the accuracy achievements are from n number of layers which is the learning absorption networks can be memorized those training data and try to verify with the external similar training dataset see the evaluation or validation results improvement.

There are many ways to increase the accuracy number you can add some layers, select the matching model or layers, add some significant data, filter or convolution layers, extract parameters and training, optimizer or loss functions.

Add some layers see provide better result immediately when you add more contrast data it provides effects fast and possible to more sample recognize but when the number of sample reach and you need input learning that is required some improvement methods.

See both ladies are looking similar with amount number of random input and validation but many be one has a bigger checks and another has a big smile :)

**[ Sample ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(50, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(50, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_validation_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(50, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_validation_label, shape=(50, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50)
validation_dataset = dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, validation_data=(validation_dataset), batch_size=100, epochs=50 )
```

**[ Output ]:**

[image: Sample]